# A case where Zariski topology of a product is the product topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm aware that, in general, the Zariski topology of a product of algebraic varieties is not necessarily the product topology. But what is an example of when the Zariski topology of a product IS the product topology?

Comment: My first thought is to work over a field other than $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Take the product of a finite set of points. Are you looking for irreducible examples?

Comment: No, I guess I just overlooked the easy ones haha. Thanks

Comment: @user95024: Martin's example is actually the only possible example. Precisely, if $X, Y$ are algebraic varieties over an algebraically closed field. Then the Zariski topology on $X\times Y$ is the product topology if and only if $X$ or $Y$ is finite. Can you work it out ?